# $ajax request cannot save into array (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i've made this function:

```
    function fetchGeo(){

var geoInfo = new Array();
 var counter = 0;


  $.ajax({
  url: 'www.URL.com/req.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'action=load',
   success: function(data){
   //console.log(data);
   $.each(data, function(i,geo){

    geoInfo[i] = new Array(geo.lat,geo.long,geo.time);
  //console.log(geoInfo);  
   });
   return geoInfo;
  }
});
}


var geoInfo = fetchGeo();
```

Every time i execute this function i can't get the data into a var somewhere else in the script.

I've already found this one, but that's a fail for me too: [Wait for .each() .getJSON request to finish before executing a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462144/wait-for-each-getjson-request-to-finish-before-executing-a-callback)

Comment: For the bajillionth time, ***ajax is asynchronous.*** The value returned from the `success` callback is **not** the value returned by `$.ajax()`. So sick of this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from function with an Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562412/return-value-from-function-with-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL loving the now unit of measure -> "bajillionth" ... can i reuse it ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not returning anything from the `fetchGeo` function, you are returning it from the anonymous success handler, and that happens *after* the `fetchGeo` function ends.

Use a callback to handle the result:

```
function fetchGeo(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'www.URL.com/req.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'action=load',
    success: function(data){
      var geoInfo = [];
      $.each(data, function(i,geo){
        geoInfo.push([geo.lat,geo.long,geo.time]);
      });
      callback(geoInfo);
    }
  });
}

fetchGeo(function(geoInfo){
  // here you can use the data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `geoInfo` array is local to the `fetchGeo` function. The anonymous function created in your `.each` cannot see that array. Move the `geoInfo` array to a higher scope, such as outside the `fetchGeo` function.

Comment: That is not the problem, as the anonymous function actually *can* see the `geoInfo` variable. The variable is put in a closure, so that the anonymous function can access it.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` is async by nature. Before you return from the function ajax has not finished executing the request so whatever you are returning is an empty array.

You can try something like this by declaring `geoInfo` as a global variable or in the outerscope of the function where you can access it.

```
var geoInfo = new Array();

function fetchGeo(){

 var counter = 0;


  $.ajax({
  url: 'www.URL.com/req.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'action=load',
   success: function(data){
   //console.log(data);
   $.each(data, function(i,geo){

    geoInfo[i] = new Array(geo.lat,geo.long,geo.time);
    //console.log(geoInfo);  
   });
  }
});
}


fetchGeo();
```

Answer (score 0):

The things called on success are asynchronius (hence the name AJAX). This means that the geoInfo array is not available. If you bring it out of the scope to global level it will work.

```
var geoInfo = new Array();
function fetchGeo() {
    var counter = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.URL.com/req.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action=load',
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i,geo){
                geoInfo[i] = new Array(geo.lat,geo.long,geo.time);
                //console.log(geoInfo);  
            });
        }
    });
}

fetchGeo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        var geoInfo = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, geo) {
            geoInfo.push([geo.lat, geo.long, geo.time]);
        });
        // Call the the function which relies on `geoInfo`
        testFunction(geoInfo);
    }
    ...
});

function testFunction(geoArr) {
    // 'geoArr' is available for processing
}
```